# Mapping user to filesystem user when UID's mismatch?

Tags: filesystems, uid

Say I have a user named *user* with UID *1001* on one system and the same user (named *user*) with another UID, let's say *1002*.

If I unplug the disk drive from the second system and plug it into the first, is there an elegant way to act as if UID 1002 on the newly added drive is the same as UID 1001 on the current system (without actually scanning the file tree and `chown`'ing 1002 to 1001)?

Comment: NFS & automount are typical goto's for this. NFS provides idmap to deal w/ this - https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share. There's also this - https://serverfault.com/questions/603987/whats-the-advantage-of-synchronizing-uid-gid-across-linux-machines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with any mechanism worth suggesting that would help in doing what you want here. The typical method that most employ is using a centrally managed service that's on their LAN which manages all the UIDs across the servers/computers.

In the past I've used FreeIPA, NIS, and LDAP to do this. As of today I use FreeIPA mainly because I find it easy to setup and manage. It has a bit of a learning curve to it, but it effectively solves the issue of having users + their data spanning across multiple servers.

This topic is pretty well covered on Serverfault as well:

- [Mapping UID and GID of local user to the mounted NFS share](https://serverfault.com/questions/514118/mapping-uid-and-gid-of-local-user-to-the-mounted-nfs-share)
- [What's the advantage of synchronizing UID/GID across Linux machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/603987/whats-the-advantage-of-synchronizing-uid-gid-across-linux-machines)

If you're interested in setting up FreeIPA this tutorial is a good place to get you started with it on CentOS 7.x, titled: [How To Set Up Centralized Linux Authentication with FreeIPA on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-centralized-linux-authentication-with-freeipa-on-centos-7). If you're more into watching videos there's this [video as well that covers the installation/setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCT6E8-j8m0).